# SQL Python throwing error when I am trying to update multiple values in a row

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
c.execute('update MainDB set name=%s, set opportunity=%s, set value=%s, set stage=%s, set startdate=%s, set lastupdate=%s where rowid = %s',(name,opportunity,value,Stage,startdate,date,rowid))
```

I have a table MainDB which has columns

```
name (text), 
opportunity (text), 
value (int), 
stage (int), 
startdate (text) 
lastupdate (text)
```

With this line of code I had wanted to update all the values in the row, but it I get an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

I am not able to find any other syntax that works on the net. What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Which library do you use?

Answer (score 3):

In an UPDATE statement, you only need to use the `SET` keyword once. Follow that with a comma-separated list of assignments.

INCORRECT:

```
update MainDB set name=%s, set opportunity=%s, set value=%s, set stage=%s, 
  set startdate=%s, set lastupdate=%s where ...
```

CORRECT:

```
update MainDB set name=%s, opportunity=%s, value=%s, stage=%s,
  startdate=%s, lastupdate=%s where ...
```

This is clear in the syntax reference and the examples shown in the [documentation for UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering so well, it solved the issue